# Qt Animation is Laggy

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QTimeLine to animate a widget which is on top of a QGraphicsView which tracks the mouse. When the right mouse button is clicked the animation begins, however when the mouse moves the animation becomes very choppy to the point where it sometimes just stops animating. I used `setUpdateInterval(10)` but it didn't help.

I am thinking that when I move the mouse the dispatcher thread is too busy to handle any animations. If that's the case can I force the animation to be handled either by spawning its own thread of bumping up its priority. Otherwise, what else could I try?

Comment: Post some code? If you are tracking the mouse by setMouseTracking(true) and you have logic happening on the event, make sure you're not doing anything heavy there. You might be spamming yourself with a bunch of calls every time the mouse moves. That's the only thing I can think of off the top of my head.